# URL redirect for pages with parameter only

Tags: php, url, redirect

**EDIT:**

if I use the script below, it creates some conflicts with other pages :

```
 if (!isset( $_GET[ "id" ] ) ) {
  header( "Location: home.php" );
 }
```

This allows visitors to access all pages with URL parameters such as: `friends.php?id=22` which i don't want. **The only URL with parameter that should be accessible for visitors is `profile.php?id=$id`**

---

Working on a small project that requires users to register/log in.

So far, if a visitor (not logged in) types in `profile.php`, they'll automatically get redirected to the homepage.

Now,  what I'm trying to accomplish is to NOT redirect them if they want to check out a user's profile in particular, like `profile.php?id=22`.

Here is what I have so far:

```
if ((!preg_match("  {(?:login|logout|signin|register|profile)\.php$}",      
$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])) && (empty($_SESSION["id"])) )
{     
    header('Location: home.php');
}
```

Unfortunately this will redirect all visitors who type in `profile.php?id=22`.

**In a nutshell,**

`profile.php` should redirect and `profile.php?id=$id` shouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be as simple as:

```
if ( !isset( $_GET[ "id" ] ) ){
  header( "Location: home.php" );
  exit();
}
```

Bassicaly, what I'm doing here is testing for the existence of the `id` key in the magic `$_GET` variable. The `$_GET` variable is populated by all the parameters you pass in your URL. If `$_GET[ "id" ]` is not set, then I redirect to `home.php`.

References:

- [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)
- [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Comment: sorry I had to unaccept your answer. I've just realized that your script would cause some conflicts with other pages. See my edited question, hope you'll be able to help.

Comment: @Lix, and you should follow by `exit()` after header redirection for security reason.

Comment: @ben - why didn't you just place this logic on `profile.php`?

Comment: @Lix indeed, this was so obvious that I did not think about it! Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this: 

if (!isset($_GET["id"]))
{     
    header('Location: home.php');
}
```